# Getting Max User Connection Error on my Wordpress Website

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

My website is now suddenly very slow and every few moment it is showing error:

Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (42000/1203): User mylibvq4_libmag already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in /home3/mylibvq4/public_html/libertatem.in/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1626
User mylibvq4_libmag already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

I contacted Hostgator but they said that I need to a close all previous connections to Database but I am not able to find how to go about it from my cPanel. They also suggested me to optimize the database such that every query is killed after 21 seconds.

Please help.

Comment: You need to figure out why your queries are running slow. Killing queries doesn't really solve the problem, it just changes it.

Comment: But it says More than 10 connections are active. How can I kill all the previous connections to database and how can I stop this process.

Comment: Again, you need to debug your slow queries. They'll just keep stacking up.

Comment: How can I figure out why the queries are slow.

Comment: /etc/php.ini is typically where you would alter your number of connections / how long they should remain active and so forth.